# 7zip, batch file, file splitting, amazon s3

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, split, 7zip

I try to to use the following batch command to start for each of the files in a the given folder 7zip and split the files into 250 MB pieces. The files should not be zipped (-mx0) because I want have low disk i/o and just want to synchronize them with amazon s3.

```
 for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\Test\') do START 7z.exe a %%f.zip -wc:\Test -oc:\TestOutput\ -v250m -mx0 -t7z
```

The problem is that the output folder is not the folder I specified, it just takes the 7zip folder. Also, the files that I am trying to split, are at least 2.7 GB big, and the output files are only 3MB...

Any ideas to the code?

Also, does anyone know alternative programs that split files and that I can run via batch file? Or tools that do the entire job for me?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Not a programming question; move to superuser.

Comment: It is a programming question... It's Windows Batch programming ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not quite get how it all applies to Amazon S3, but you can use [CloudBerry Explorer PRO](http://pro.cloudberrylab.com) to break down files into small pieces and automate the transfer to S3.

Comment: this is pretty much what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I use a program called SFK, it's a true "Swiss Army Knife". It has splitting functionality:

http://stahlforce.com/dev/index.php?tool=split

(Just to make it clearer, it's commandline, very easy to use and powerful, but this splitting is not zipped, just as you want. It also joins files later.)

Comment: nice tool, already tried this, but the CPU looks horrible... on my dev server it goes up to 55%, whereas 7zip keeps it pretty low with 12%.

Comment: Whoa, 55% CPU? I use it all the time and never uses too much CPU... The weirdest part of that is the fact that file splitting is almost just a HDD operation; very weird...

Answer (score 0):

```
it just takes the 7zip folder.
```

it puts the splited files in the current working directory

7zip folder was probably your current working directory try changing it to your output folder and see if it works